# How to upload file in Hadoop using Java Api

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop2

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import java.net.URI;

public class HdfsCon 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception      
    {        
        String HdfsUrl="hdfs://172.16.32.139:9000";
        Configuration conf=new Configuration();
        //conf.set("fs.default.name", HdfsUrl);
        URI uri=new URI(HdfsUrl);

        FileSystem fs= FileSystem.get(URI.create(HdfsUrl),conf);

        String fp="/home/user1/Documents/hive-site.xml";
        String tp="/fifo_tbl";

        fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path(fp),new Path(tp));    
    }
}
```

When I try to execute the above java program, it gave me the below error. 
I'm trying to upload file in hadoop through java code.
(Hadoop version 2.9.0)

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: The obvious thing indicated by the error is a version mismatch. Can you use the same hadoop version for your client as for the server you're connecting to?

Comment: what is  your maven dependencies  some version  are too low

Comment: I'm directly export jar to the project. @H.king

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show how you did that? Which jar file do you have?